# R studio not working on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: r, ubuntu, installation, rstudio

I converted to Ubuntu today, but have a problems launching R studio. I installed R through the command prompt like this:

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key E084DAB9

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/">> /etc/apt/sources.list'

gpg -a --export E084DAB9 | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get -y install r-base
```

I cheked if R was installed proper by typing `R` and then exiting by `q(save="no")`.

I installed R studio through the command prompt by

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
wget https://download2.rstudio.org/rstudio-server-0.99.902-amd64.deb
sudo gdebi rstudio-server-0.99.902-amd64.deb
```

But this doesn't work and i can't find the launch button or open R studio. 
Afterwards i tried to remove it and install it through the website but doesn't work either. What should i do?

Comment: I did it through the Ubuntu Software Center.  It was really easy that way.  Download RStudio, then click "open in software center" (or something similar).  Then you can install there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no lauch button -- you connect to port 8787 on the machine running RStudio Server.

In other words, type `http://localhost:8787` in the address bar of your browser. You should see a login screen with the RStudio logo.  This connects you to your RStudio *Server*.

If you want to run the *Desktop* version you need to install the other available .deb package.

Comment: Thank you! it works now so that is perfect. But i would like the dekstop version so the other ´.deb´ file? Do you know the name and how to do it or maybe got a link?

Comment: @Soren Just go to the rstudio website and pay more attention when you're choosing what to download

Comment: It is on the same page, but not under 'RStudio Server' but rather 'RStudio Desktop'.

Answer (score 1):

For those on Ubuntu 16.10, or who prefer to use the desktop version of RStudio, you may wish to follow the solution posted by [Mike Williamson](https://mikewilliamson.wordpress.com/2016/11/14/installing-r-studio-on-ubuntu-16-10/) reproduced below:

1) Get the latest R Studio Daily Build [here](https://www.rstudio.org/download/daily/desktop/ubuntu64/), though note that it's not necessarily stable.

2) Install, chaning the name of the package to the one you downloaded - perhaps easiest if you go to your Downloads directory - and you'll probably find that there are missing packages:

> $ sudo dpkg -i rstudio-1.0.124-amd64.deb

3) Download the missing packages (the lack of which causes the installation to fail):

> $ wget http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gstreamer0.10/libgstreamer0.10-0_0.10.36-1.5_amd64.deb
>
> $ wget http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gst-plugins-base0.10/libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0_0.10.36-2_amd64.deb

4) Install them:

> $ sudo dpkg -i libgstreamer0.10-0_0.10.36-1.5_amd64.deb
>
> $ sudo dpkg -i libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0_0.10.36-2_amd64.deb

5) Make sure they don't get over-written at the next software update:

> $ sudo apt-mark hold libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0
>
> $ sudo apt-mark hold libgstreamer0.10

6) Install RStudio (changing name to the version you downloaded):

> sudo gdebi rstudio-1.1.5-amd64.deb

7) Launch RStudio:

> rstudio